# Get a simple JSONP object from a remote server php file using ajax (and jquery) embedded in javascript directly in my wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have some php written on a static wordpress page (using the include-php-in-pages-and-posts plugin) that gets a JSON object from a remote server. This of course just works once on page load, and then never again (as it is not ajax).

But as the call is sent to a server with its own php and through an API url call, then I'm sure there is no need for my php and there must be a simple bit of ajax (possibly using jquery) that I can write directly on my html wordpress page that gets the JSON object from a remote server, all just with the javascript I'm using directly on my pages.

(I imagine it would use the JSONP format as it is from a remote server) - something like :

```
$.get( "my_url.php_with_API-KEY_etc", data, success, "jsonp" );
```

or

```
$.getJSONP("my_url.php_with_API-KEY_etc"
```

As you can see, I'm a bit lost. Is this too "beginner" a question for this this forum? Or can anyone help?

If it's too beginner, any tutorial suggestions? (I have tried all the ones from first 3 pages that come up on google). I'm feeling this is such a simple request it should't be this hard.

The php code (that works only page load as I use it through the 'included-php-on-pages-and-posts' plugin) is :

```
[php]
ob_start();
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://us01.proxy.teleduino.org/api/1.0/328.php?k={MY-API-KEY-HERE}&r=getAnalogInput&pin=14');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$results = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
$data = json_decode($results, true);
$mess = $data['message'];
$stat = $data['status'];
$moisture = $data['response']['values'][0];
$time = $data['response']['time'];
[/php]
```

Been struggling for many days, read hundreds of other related answers, but no answer seems to simply explain how I do this with ajax/jquery and js alone for wordpress. Thank you in advance.

Comment: doing just fine asking well constructed question like htis with concise description of problem, steps taken to research and well presented code.Ideal for you would be a wordpress plugin that acts as an AAJX output controller so you can call it through the wordpress framework. You could slide your CURL code right in it. Afraid I don't do much in wordpress any more to help...but someone should give you suggestions

Comment: I'll check this again later on, and this is just a heads up. What your PHP-in-Posts plugin does is a [*Shortcode*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) and, IMO, you'll be better off creating your own. Which brings us to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13614297) -> Shortcode + Ajax

Comment: Thank you charlietfl and b_ for the encouragement. So then I guess finding or making a plugin is the best way. I am searching for "wordpress plugin that acts as an AAJX output controller" but not finding anything that makes sense to me, and b_ I'm just going through your our plugin code suggested now to see if I can make sense of it so I can maybe customize it to my needs (if that's what you are suggesting?). Thanks again. Any more tips on this or maybe resources for how to find/make the right plugin for this greatly appreciated.

Comment: I doubt you'll find the "right plugin" and will have to roll your own. I've posted an Answer and hope it's a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd solve this creating a Shortcode Plugin to handle this specific case. What a plugin like `include-php-in-pages-and-posts` does **is a Shortcode**. And what you're trying is too complex to be laying together with the HTML content (and all sorts of code mangling can happen inside WP visual/text-editor).

Here there is a full plugin example on [How to Use AJAX in a WordPress Shortcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13614297)

- rename the shortcode to your liking, e.g, `add_shortcode( 'teleduino', array( $this, 'shortcode') );`.
- your actual PHP code has to be adapted into the methods `shortcode()` and `get_random_posts()`. This `get_random_posts()` would be your `get_teleduino_response()` and responsible exclusively for getting the response and returning the data or an error message. Then in `shortcode()` you process the result and do the actual output.
- the Shortcode also outputs a button that triggers the Ajax call that executes `get_random_posts()` again in `query_rand_post()`.
- in sum, you gotta adapt this three methods (functions inside a class) to your logic.
- I think you can drop the `ob_start` and send the response back to jQuery with `wp_send_json_success( $results );`, or do some pre-processing of the result and send back only relevant info
- maybe instead of cUrl, you could use [`wp_remote_get()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13638937)

Comment: B_ Thank you this is awesome. I've done a simpler temporary quick fix to get me out of trouble for the next day or so, where I just use my old php files and call them with ajax from the html pages. Your plugin definitely seems the way to go really and is my next step. I'll work through your answer and let you know how it went once I've rolled that. Many thanks again.